# XMLHttpRequest code working in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

So I have this code right here to intercept AJAX requests in a page:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testing
// @namespace   testing
// @description testing
// @include     http://www.google.com*
// @include     https://www.google.com*
// @version     1
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        this.addEventListener("loadend", function(evt) {
            console.log("Complete");
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open)
```

It works on Chrome ver. 59 but not on Firefox ver. 55
Is it due to deprecated code?
Is there a workaround to this?

Edit: Sorry if I should've mentioned this earlier but I'm doing the code in Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey. Re-edited the code above

Comment: what happens in firefox? is your code simply not executed? or does something else "happen"

Comment: It doesn't get executed, it seems to simply ignore the whole code, it doesn't even give me any errors or the sort.

Comment: I've just tested your code in Firefox (55) and it works fine - is this code "loaded" very early in the page? i.e. first script tag?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently testing it on a new script file which only contain the codes I provided earlier on but its still not working for some reason, I'l try using the ver. 55 to see if it'll work for me.

Comment: 54 works as well (I just use 55 because I need to)

Comment: Do you have any plugin installed and active which could themselves overwrite XHR's proto ? Also does the same request, without your modification does work in FF ?

Comment: in the console once the page loads, what does `console.log(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open + '')` output? your code? or `function open() {
    [native code]
}`

Comment: personally, I'd use `load` or `loadend` events rather than checking old school `readystatechange` + `readyState== 4` - but that's just me :p

Comment: I did mention `loadend`, didn't I? plus you're assumption is incorrect anyway - a 404 will **not** prevent a `load` event - only an `error` or `abort` or `timeout` will do that

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX, I fixed the code by changing readystatechange to loadend and it works now. I re-edited my code above to reflect the change.

Comment: oh!!! this is a greasemonkey script - that does change everything - don't you have to change `unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` instead?

Comment: I didn't have to, the script seems to work just fine without using unsafeWindow. I only had to change the readystatechange to loadend for the script to work. Thank you again though.

Answer (score -3):

**Sometimes firefox is not allow XMLHttpRequest**,

**So update the firefox version or uninstall and again install.**

Comment: This is pure "speculation" at best

Comment: Theses answers needs some documentation to sustentation, this for welfare of community.